# Can `area=""` of the default route be changed to non-empty string value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

When creating a new MVC project in Visual Studio, the navigation bar that is created in the `_Layout.cshtml` file contains the link shown below. It serves the purpose of being the "Home" button for your application, and the `area=""` value indicates the default area.

It works fine enough, but I was wondering if it possible to replace `""` with a named value.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sample", "Index", "Home", 
      new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

I looked at the default route and didn't see any parameters for area.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  
             UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Is there some easy tweak I can make so that `area=""` can be written as `area="default", or some other non-empty value?

Comment: If you make the area a non-empty value, then you will be calling a non-default area. Of course, there is nothing preventing you from not using one and moving all of your "default" code into an area named "default", which would enable you to use `area="default"`. But it is unclear from your question why `area=""` is a problem. This is [the way Microsoft recommends to "unset" route values](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346), since they are always carried over from the current request into the URLs on the view.

Comment: It's not a problem in that sense.. I have a function that allows a user to filter mvc sitemap values based on area. In my normal logic a choice  of "" is interpreted as "don't filter and give me everything." But because `area=""` is a legitimate value, I have to have an extra set of logic steps to tell the user that area="" is really the default area and provide a different way to provide all results while not changing the convention they're used to. I figured the answer to the question I posed might provide an answer on a system level instead of an action level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ActionLink/RouteLink/UrlHelper there is a special case where you have to put the `area` into the route values collection.

However, under the covers MVC actually uses `DataTokens["area"]` to determine what area to match. So if you are comparing against the current request, you could check whether `DataTokens["area"]` exists - if not, it indicates a request for the default area.

You can also set that parameter on the routes in your route configuration if you want them to be specific to an area.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  
         UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).DataTokens["area"] = "default";
```